# Grails 3: External Logback.groovy file

Tags: grails, gradle, logback, grails-3.0, logback-groovy

I'm trying to externalize my `logback.groovy` file by setting the path in my `build.gradle` file in the bootrun closure:

```
bootRun {
    if (Environment.currentEnvironment == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
        jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=2g', '-Xmx2g', '-Dlogging.config=/path/to/config/logback.groovy']
    } else {
        jvmArgs = ['-XX:MaxPermSize=2g', '-Xmx2g']
    }
}
```

But I am getting:

```
.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.groovy] at [file:/Users/name/workspace/project/build/resources/main/logback.groovy]
```

It keeps reading from the classpath and not from the external file...
Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by adding `-Dlogging.config=/path/to/config/logback.groovy` as a system property in tomcat.