# How does a Grails plugin add its own logback.groovy?

Tags: grails, logback, grails-plugin, logback-groovy

Just like to define custom `Bootstrap.groovy` or `UrlMappings.groovy` in a Grails plugin, we can define `FooBootstrap.groovy` or `FooUrlMappings.groovy` so that those can be bundled in the plugin because the earlier are excluded by default. http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html#_excluded_artefacts

How can we do the same for `logback.groovy`? I have a multi-project build where a single Grails plugin is used by 3 different Grails application.

**My research & trials:**

1. I tried creating a `foo-logback.groovy` but that is not loading.
2. [Grails 3: External Logback.groovy file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853935/grails-3-external-logback-groovy-file)

Answer (score 2):

Another resource: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Basically, there can only be one `logback.groovy` or `logback.xml` in the classpath. In order to achieve what you are asking you could use your root project's `logback.groovy` and load a `foo-logback.groovy` using a `GroovyShell` instance (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006034/260487).

Alternatively you can have the plugin resources defined in its own package and include that package in your root `logback.groovy` file. For example, instead of `com.example.FooService` you would define it as `com.example.plugin.foo.FooService`, and you'd define a log rule for the `com.example.plugin.foo` package.

Comment: Nice resource. I'll try that out.